# Determining a limit without L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{h(\pi+h)}$$ without using L'Hospital's rule. It's part of a problem for which I am trying to prove that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{|\pi+h|}-\frac{h}{\pi}}{|h|}$$ exists. After a bit of simplifying and assuming $h>0$ I have arrived at the first expression.

Comment: What is $x$ here?

Comment: Mistake. I meant $h\to0$

Comment: The easiest way to remember $\sin(\pi+h)=-\sin h$ is using the following identity for suplementary angles: $\sin(\pi+h)=\sin(\pi-(\pi+h))=\sin(-h)=-\sin h$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{h(\pi+h)}&=-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h} \cdot\frac1{\pi+h}\\
&=-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1{\pi+h}\\
&=-\frac1\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

With high-school tools:
$$\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{h(\pi+h)}=-\underbrace{\frac{\sinh}{h}}_{\substack{\downarrow\\1}}\underbrace{\frac1{\pi+h}}_{\substack{ \downarrow\\ 1/\pi}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin(\pi + h) = -\sin(h)$. We can use the Taylor series of $\sin$ to arrive at

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h + h^3/3! - h^5/5! + ...}{h(\pi + h)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1 + h^2/3! - h^4/5! + ...}{\pi + h} = -\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\sin (h+\pi )=-\sin(h)$$

Thus the limit is $$ \lim _{h\to 0}-((\sin h)/h )(1/\pi )=(-1/\pi)$$

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach consists in using the following results
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1\\\\
\displaystyle \sin(\pi + h) = -\sin(h)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

At your case, we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(\pi + h)}{h(\pi + h)} = -\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{\sin(h)}{h}\times\frac{1}{\pi + h}\right] = -\frac{1}{\pi}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to evaluate $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{-\sin h}{h}\cdot\frac{1}{\pi+h}=-\frac{1}{\pi}$, so that you can then prove the existence of$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{|\pi+h|}-\frac{h}{\pi}}{|h|}.$$Since the latter two-sided limit is of an odd function of $h$, to exist we need it to be $0$. As $h\to0$,$$\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{|\pi+h|}-\frac{h}{\pi}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin h}{1+h/\pi}+h\right)\sim\frac{-2h}{\pi},$$so division by $|h|$ gives $-\frac{2h}{\pi|h|}$ as the asymptotic behaviour. Thus the limit you wanted to exist doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\sin(\pi+h)=-\sin h$ then

$$\frac{\sin(\pi+h)}{h(\pi+h)}=\frac{-\sin(h)}{h}\cdot\frac{1}{\pi+h}\to-1\cdot \frac1\pi=-\frac1\pi$$